# How do i change the jquery icons color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery mobile icons. I have a little confusion here to change the actual icon color to red and background to white. See below html code.

```
<div data-role="page"><div data-role="content">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">  </a</div></div>
```

Such that the icon should be as follows

[image: Icons should be like this]

See  [**JS FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVnZw/130/)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: this is not duplicate to what it is marked to!

Comment: Find the elements to be changed, in this case .ui-btn-icon-notext .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon {margin: 2px 1px 2px 3px;float: left;} (this is default), add background-color: #ff0000; here put these in ext style sheet  and add it to your head(after the jquery default css file), another solution is make a custom class forex class="mybtn" define your css and put !impotant into it.

Comment: Also you can use "style=background-color:red" inside <span> {find this span tag using browser inspector}

Comment: @jai wrong dup answer, the icons are SVG.

Comment: @Omar i didn't find it, where is it?

Comment: You can change background's color with css. To change SVG's icon color, you need to to modify JQM style sheet, icon by icon.

Comment: @jai http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/

Comment: what about the **fallback png's**. @omar

Comment: try using http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/

Comment: @jai did the op ask about fallback icons?

Comment: @Omar as you posted the link i just pointed the fallback, what if in case that's it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a data-theme attribute, and you can create themes using jQuery Mobile themeroller. 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVnZw/130/) with a different color.

```
     <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b"></a></div>
```

If you don't want to create your own themes for jQuery Mobile, then use an inspector and find the right element, then add css to it. For example:

```
.ui-btn-icon-notext .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon {
      background-color: #111;
 }
```

Update:
You have to create your own icon and then change the icon background image:

```
.ui-btn-icon-notext .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon {

    background: url(http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2165/office/48/home_01.png);
    background-size: 17px;

}
```

Comment: I would like to change the icon color to red see image above

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it helps you. You will have to create icons in the color(s) you want.